# How to assign a random integer to a variable to feed as parameter to fibonacci generator?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I want to print a **fibonacci sequence** up to a random number. First I defined a variable (`nterm`) and assigned an integer number to it. It is actually the range to which the program will print a **fibonacci sequence**. 
 I want to do it by generating a random number, so I included the random library with `import random`. Here a random number is generated but I want to assign that number to `nterms` (a variable).
 How can I assign a random number to `nterms`.

```
import random
print(random.randint(0,5))
 # Here a random number should be generated and should be used as nterms           

    n1 = 0
    n2 = 1
    count = 0
    if nterms <= 0:
       print("Please enter a positive integer")
    elif nterms == 1:
       print("Fibonacci sequence upto",nterms,":")
       print(n1)
    else:
       print("Fibonacci sequence upto",nterms,":")
       while count < nterms:
           print(n1,end=' , ')
           nth = n1 + n2
           n1 = n2
           n2 = nth
           count += 1
```

**For example:** the random number generated is 5 so it should be equal to nterms. 

 If `nterms = 5` the expected output should be `0 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 ,`

Comment: I want to say that if random number is 5 so it should be equal to nterms.

Comment: I want to run it by generating a random number

Comment: How can a assign a random number to nterms using random library.

Comment: If your question is about `How can a assign a random number to nterms using random library.` ... why all the rest of the code and text ? use `nterm = random.randint(lowestvalue,biggestvalue)`

Comment: your current code uses variable assignment all over the place ... maybe it is some code you "found"? in that case you might profit from learning a bit more about python - start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are not assigning any value to `nterms`.
You should assign it like the following:

```
nterms = random.randint(0,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nterms = random.randint(0,5)
```

This is simply how you can assign a random number in variable and pass it later. Any more questions, let me know. 
edit:

Like patrick said, the format of this is `nterms =random.randint(lowestvalue,biggestvalue)`

So you can add the range of the numbers you want to test with, in that case you **do not** have to check if it is less than zero in your code,

```
  if nterms <= 0:
       print("Please enter a positive integer")
```

because it will never be less than zero, if you enter two positive numbers as the lowest and biggest values. :)

Comment: You might want to assign it to `nterms` so it's a little more clear.

Comment: You want to say that i should write it as nterms=random.randint (0,5)